# Cutting rows from one sheet and pasting into another in the same workbook - Error 438

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to both colour rows in OC according to the catogarization in column A in OC. Once and issue is closed "C" I want that row cut and pasted into sheet CC. The Debug highlights line `Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 11)).Style = "O"`

My next challenge will be to delete the now emplty row from OC, and shifing the remainig rows up.

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim OC As Worksheet
Set OC = wb.Sheets("Commercial")

Dim CC As Worksheet
Set CC = wb.Sheets("Closed Commercial")

lrow = OC.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
clrow = CC.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 8 To lrow
    For w = 8 To clrow
   
            If Cells(r, 1) = "O" Then
            Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 11)).Style = "O"
    
            ElseIf Cells(r, 1) = "EO" Then
            Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 11)).Style = "EO"
    
            ElseIf Cells(r, 1) = "ED" Then
            Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 8)).Style = "ED"
    
            ElseIf Cells(r, 1) = "RDU" Then
            Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 11)).Style = "RDU"
            
            ElseIf Cells(r, 1) = "RFQs" Then
            Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 11)).Style = "RFQs"
    
        End If
    
        If Cells(r, 12) = "C" Then
        
            Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 12)).Cut
            Range(Cells(w, 1), Cells(w, 12)).Paste
        
        End If
    
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Next
    Next


End Sub


''UPDATE:

'This is my new code, it got rid of the 450 error, but in its stead I am 'getting Object doesn't support this method (438):

    ' Macro2 Macro
'
Sub Macro2()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim OC As Worksheet
Set OC = wb.Sheets("Commercial")

Dim CC As Worksheet
Set CC = wb.Sheets("Closed Commercial")

lrow = OC.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
clrow = CC.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


    For r = 8 To lrow
        
            If OC.Cells(r, 1) = "Origin" Then
            OC.Range(OC.Cells(r, 1), OC.Cells(r, 11)).Style = "Origin"
    
            ElseIf Cells(r, 1) = "Open" Then
            OC.Range(OC.Cells(r, 1), OC.Cells(r, 11)).Style = "Open"
    
            ElseIf Cells(r, 1) = "Disco" Then
            OC.Range(OC.Cells(r, 1), OC.Cells(r, 8)).Style = "Disco"
        
            ElseIf OC.Cells(r, 1) = "RDU" Then
            OC.Range(OC.Cells(r, 1), OC.Cells(r, 11)).Style = "RDU"
            
            ElseIf OC.Cells(r, 1) = "RFQs" Then
            OC.Range(OC.Cells(r, 1), OC.Cells(r, 11)).Style = "RFQs"
    
    
       End If

    Next
    
        For r = 8 To lrow
        For w = 8 To clrow
        
            If OC.Cells(r, 12) = "C" Then
        
                OC.Range(OC.Cells(r, 7), OC.Cells(r, 12)).Style = "Closed"
                OC.Range(OC.Cells(r, 1), OC.Cells(r, 12)).Copy
                'the line below is the issue
                CC.Range(CC.Cells(w, 1)).Paste


                
        End If
        
        Next
        Next
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        
        
End Sub
```

Comment: The styles aren't the issue, I created them in the formatting of the sheet itself

Comment: Yes, they are the issue. The error message is telling you this: "Invalid property assignment".

Comment: You're all set up with `OC` and `CC` objects, make sure you [qualify all your `Range` references](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/5110/qualifying-references).

Comment: @BigBen, thanks for the input, before introducing the sheet names this exact coding works.

Comment: Then as @PeterT mentioned, *qualify* all your `Range` (and `Cells`) references with the appropriate worksheet. Though, I thought `Style`s belonged to the workbook, not worksheet, could be wrong.

Comment: A `Range` does not have a `Paste` method.

Comment: `CC.Range(CC.Cells(w, 1))`  -----> `CC.Cells(w, 1)`. No outer `Range`.

Comment: I've tried changing to 
'CC.Cells(w, 1).Select
Selection.Paste'
I'm still getting the same error though. Thanks for all the help btw.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who took time to comment and answer, this is the final version of the code that works exactly the way I want it to:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim OC As Worksheet
Set OC = wb.Sheets("Commercial")

Dim CC As Worksheet
Set CC = wb.Sheets("Closed Commercial")

lrow = OC.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
clrow = CC.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


For r = 8 To lrow
    
        If Cells(r, 1) = "O" Then
        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 11)).Style = "O"

        ElseIf Cells(r, 1) = "EO" Then
        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 11)).Style = "EO"

        ElseIf Cells(r, 1) = "ED" Then
        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 8)).Style = "ED"

        ElseIf Cells(r, 1) = "RDU" Then
        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 11)).Style = "RDU"
        
        ElseIf Cells(r, 1) = "RFQs" Then
        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 11)).Style = "RFQs"


   End If

Next

    For r = 8 To lrow

    
        If OC.Cells(r, 12) = "C" Then
        
        OC.Range(OC.Cells(r, 7), OC.Cells(r, 12)).Style = "Closed"
        
        OC.Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Copy CC.Cells(clrow, 1)
        OC.Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        clrow = clrow + 1
            
    End If
    
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    
    
End Sub
```